# Retrieving data from two tables in one row with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get date from two tables, but problem is that they are returning multiple rows for individual id.
I have tables like these:-

```
Transaction
-----------
tid|startdate|enddate|status
100|2-9-2015|2-9-2015|success
200|1-9-2015|1-9-2015|failed
300|31-8-2015|31-8-2015|success

Test_Details
------------
id|tid|test_name|test_status
1|100|Test1|yes
2|100|Tes2|no
3|100|Test3|yes
4|200|Test1|no
5|200|Tes2|no
6|200|Test3|yes
7|300|Test1|yes
8|300|Tes2|no
9|300|Test3|no
```

Desired result :-

```
tid|startdate|enddate|status|Test1|Test2|Test3
100|2-9-2015|2-9-2015|success|yes|no|yes
200|1-9-2015|1-9-2015|failed|no|no|yes
300|31-8-2015|31-8-2015|success|yes|no|no
```

I am using this query:-

```
select distinct ts.tid as tid, ts.startdate as startdate,
ts.enddate as enddate, ts.status as status, 
CASE WHEN (td.test_name='Test1') THEN test_status END as Test1,
CASE WHEN (td.test_name='Test2') THEN test_status END as Test2,
CASE WHEN (td.test_name='Test3') THEN test_status END as Test3
from transation ts, test_details td where ts.tid =td.id
```

But I'm getting multiple rows.
Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e981c) demo

Answer (score 1):

As long as test_details isn't a temporary table you can do the following:

```
SELECT ts.tid, ts.startdate, ts.enddate, ts.status,
  t1.test_status Test1,
  t2.test_status Test2,
  t3.test_status Test3
 FROM transaction ts
  LEFT JOIN test_details t1 ON (t1.tid=ts.tid AND t1.test_name='Test1')
  LEFT JOIN test_details t2 ON (t2.tid=ts.tid AND t2.test_name='Test2')
  LEFT JOIN test_details t3 ON (t3.tid=ts.tid AND t3.test_name='Test3');
```

This is under the assumption that transaction.tid is unique and (tid, test_name) pair in test_details is unique.

**EDIT:** In reply to OPs comment *"It's working but it is slow on large db"* I'd suggest to add indexes to `test_details.tid` and `test_details.test_name`:

```
ALTER TABLE test_details ADD INDEX (tid);
ALTER TABLE test_details ADD INDEX (test_name);
```

Also, if all three tests are known to exist for all transactions you may want to use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT ts.tid, ts.startdate, ts.enddate, ts.status,
  t1.test_status Test1,
  t2.test_status Test2,
  t3.test_status Test3
 FROM transaction ts
  JOIN test_details t1 ON (t1.tid=ts.tid AND t1.test_name='Test1')
  JOIN test_details t2 ON (t2.tid=ts.tid AND t2.test_name='Test2')
  JOIN test_details t3 ON (t3.tid=ts.tid AND t3.test_name='Test3');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GROUP BY query, for example with GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function:

```
SELECT
  ts.tid as tid,
  ts.startdate as startdate,
  ts.enddate as enddate,
  ts.status as status,
  GROUP_CONCAT(test_status ORDER BY td.test)
FROM
  transation ts LEFT JOIN test_details td ON ts.tid =td.id
GROUP BY
  ts.tid,
  ts.startdate,
  ts.enddate,
  ts.status
```

or this query if you want to have status in different columns:

```
SELECT
  ts.tid as tid,
  ts.startdate as startdate,
  ts.enddate as enddate,
  ts.status as status, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN (td.test_name='Test1') THEN test_status END) as Test1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (td.test_name='Test2') THEN test_status END) as Test2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (td.test_name='Test3') THEN test_status END) as Test3
FROM
  transation ts LEFT JOIN test_details td ON ts.tid =td.id
GROUP BY
  ts.tid,
  ts.startdate,
  ts.enddate,
  ts.status
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying second one, but it's taking too much time for the execution.

Comment: @NikhilGupta do you have an index on transaction.tid ? and one on test_details.id? that should improve performances

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    ts.tid as tid, 
    ts.startdate as startdate,
    ts.enddate as enddate, 
    ts.status as status, 
    group_concat(test1) test1, 
    group_concat(test2) test2, 
    group_concat(test3) test3 
  from 
    (select 
        ts.tid as tid, 
        ts.status as status, 
        CASE WHEN (td.test_name='Test1') THEN test_status END as Test1,
        CASE WHEN (td.test_name='Tes2') THEN test_status END as Test2,
        CASE WHEN (td.test_name='Test3') THEN test_status END as Test3
      from 
         transation ts 
       join 
         test_details td 
       on ts.tid=td.tid
      ) t 
 group by tid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own query just after adding group by clause-

```
select distinct ts.tid as tid, ts.startdate as startdate,
ts.enddate as enddate, ts.status as status, 
CASE WHEN (td.test_name='Test1') THEN test_status END as Test1,
CASE WHEN (td.test_name='Test2') THEN test_status END as Test2,
CASE WHEN (td.test_name='Test3') THEN test_status END as Test3
from transation ts, test_details td 
where ts.tid =td.id 
group by ts.tid;
```

Comment: Hi Zafar, In this case I am getting on Test1 value and others are null